# C# MailBee MailMessage Properties (extended properties?)

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I'm using MailBee.Net 12.1.1.620 (for .net 4.5).

Question regarding properties of MailBee.Mime.MailMessage object. I don't see rather common properties such as: Categories, ConversationIndex, SearchKey. And there is no way except of read of raw headers to read some extended properties by MAPI tag. I'm opening msg and eml files directly from files.

Do I miss some component which give access to extended properties or its just not supported by mailbee yet ?

Comment: Hope this Official Documentation helps. They have properties to Get the Headers and Raw Header of the Mail Message. https://afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/MailBee.Mime.MailMessage.html

Comment: If certain header is available in EML message, you can get it as `msg.Headers["headername"].Value`